# has_one value not created yet, not showing up in form and err'ing out as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model:

```
class item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :price
end

class price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end


def 
  if !@item.price
    @item.price.build
  end
end
```

I get:

```
 undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

How would I build the price for an item if the price doesn't exit in the prices table?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@price = @item.price || @item.build_price
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html